Autoscrolling a "details" component full of "detailsCards" to a constituency after you click on said ocnstituency on a map svg
I am trying to implement an autoscroll function. I have rendered a map where all of the constituencies of Singapore are. There is a details scrollable (on the webpage) to the right of the map. Basically, I want the scrollable to scroll to the card where the constituency names match. For example if i were to click on constituency A on the svg, the scrollable should scroll to constituency A's details (card). I am using refs to accomplish this, however code is not functional. I have 4 components, the MapSection, where the scrollable and the svg are, the MapChart, which is the svg and the MapScrollable, which houses the MapScrollableCards which have render all the data which is fetched inside the scrollable component.
I am trying to accomplish it this way
Inside the map svg
const MapChart:React.FC<MapChartProps> = ({onConstituencyClick}) => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const supabase = getSupabaseBrowserClient();
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useQuery(get_main_map_data(supabase));
  const constituencyData = data;
  const getConstituencyColor = (name: string) => {
    const constituencyInfo = (constituencyData ?? []).find(
      (c) => c.name === name,
    );
    return constituencyInfo ? constituencyInfo.color : '#D6D6DA';
  };
  return (
    <div className='w-[34rem] md:w-11/12 -translate-x-32'>
      <ComposableMap className='stroke-black'>
        <Geographies
          geography={SgMap}
          fill='#D6D6DA'
          stroke='#FFFFFF'
          strokeWidth='0.6px'
        >
          {({ geographies }) =>
            geographies.map((geo) => (
              <Geography
                key={geo.rsmKey}
                geography={geo}
                data-tooltip-id='my-tooltip'
                data-tip-content={geo.properties.name}
                onMouseEnter={() => {
                  setContent(geo.properties.name);

                  setIsOpen(true);
                }}
                onMouseLeave={() => {
                  setIsOpen(false);
                }}
                onClick={() => {
                  onConstituencyClick(geo.properties.name.toUpperCase());
                }}
                style={{
                  default: {
                    fill: `#${getConstituencyColor(geo.properties.name)}`,
                    outline: 'none',
                    
                  },
                  hover: {
                    fill: `#${getConstituencyColor(geo.properties.name)}`,
                    opacity: 0.8,
                    outline: 'none',
                  },
                  pressed: {
                    fill: `#${getConstituencyColor(geo.properties.name)}`,
                    outline: '#607D8B',
                  },
                }}
              />
            ))
          }
        </Geographies>
/// and so on

Inside the MapSection
const mapScrollableRef = useRef<MapScrollableRef>(null);

  const handleConstituencyClick = (constituencyName: string) => {
  
    if (mapScrollableRef.current) {
      mapScrollableRef.current.scrollToConstituency(constituencyName);
    }
    return null;
  };
return
<>
//......more code
 <div className='relative'>
          <MapChart onConstituencyClick={handleConstituencyClick} />
        </div>
     
      <div className='lg:absolute w-fit top-4 right-1 md:right-0'>
        <MapScrollable ref={mapScrollableRef}/>
      </div>
    </>

The MapScrollable
const MapScrollable = forwardRef<MapScrollableRef>((props, ref) => {
  const scrollAreaRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const cardRefs = useRef<CardRefs>({});

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    scrollToConstituency: (constituencyName: string) => {
  
      const cardElement = cardRefs.current[constituencyName.toUpperCase()];

      if (cardElement && scrollAreaRef.current) {
        console.log('Scrolling to element:', cardElement);
        setTimeout(() => {
          scrollAreaRef.current?.scrollTo({
            top: cardElement.offsetTop,
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }, 100);
      } else {
        console.log('Card or scroll area not found');
      }
    }
  }));

  const setCardRef = useCallback((element: HTMLDivElement | null, constituencyName: string) => {
    if (element) {
      console.log(`Setting ref for constituency: ${constituencyName}`);
      cardRefs.current[constituencyName.toUpperCase()] = element;
    } else {
      console.log(`Failed to set ref for constituency: ${constituencyName}`);
    }
  }, []);

  const supabase = getSupabaseBrowserClient();
  const {
    data: electoralData,
    error,
    isLoading,
  } = useQuery(get_map_data(supabase));

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Electoral data loaded:', electoralData ? electoralData.length : 0);
    console.log('scrollAreaRef is set:', !!scrollAreaRef.current);
  }, [electoralData]);

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>Error loading data: {error.message}</div>;
  if (!electoralData || electoralData.length === 0) {
    return <div>No electoral data available.</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className='relative items-center'>
      <ScrollArea className='h-[48rem] space-y-2 overflow-hidden hidden lg:block' ref={scrollAreaRef}>
        {electoralData.map((data, index) => (
          <div key={index} ref={(el) => setCardRef(el, data.constituency)}>
            <MapScrollabeCard data={data} id={data.constituency} />
          </div>
        ))}
        <ScrollBar classThumb='bg-stone-600' orientation='vertical' />
      </ScrollArea>
    //more code and closing tags

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Note that i want to scroll the component, not the entire page (to reiterate)
